# Using Dictionary Parameters as Optional Arguments when Calling Method

Tags: c#, optional-parameters

I'm presently trying to use a dictionary values to name optional parameters when invoking a method. I'm not sure this is possible with c# but I do something similar with queries using dynamic SQL.

```
string[] dobArrayKey = {"dob: "};
string[] dobArrayValue = {txtDob.Text};
string[] ptntNumArrayKey = { "PatientID: " };
string[] ptntNumArrayValue = { txtOfficeMR.Text};
string[] nameArrayKey = { "FirstName: ", "LastName: " };
string[] nameArrayValue = { txtFirstname.Text, txtLastname.Text };

List<List<string>> searchResults = new List<List<string>>();


Dictionary<string[], string[]> searchCriteria = new Dictionary<string[], string[]> 
{ 
    {dobArrayKey,dobArrayValue}
    ,{ptntNumArrayKey,ptntNumArrayValue}
    ,{nameArrayKey,nameArrayValue}
};

foreach (var item in searchCriteria)
{
    if (item.Value[0] != "" && item.Value[0] != null)
    {
        searchResults.Add(new List<string>());

        for (int x = 0; x <= item.Key.Count(); x++)
        {
            string strJSON = doPatientSearch(Convert.ToInt32(au.UserID)
                , Convert.ToInt32(Session["PracticeID"]), au.SessionID, item.Key[x].ToString() : item.Value[x].ToString() );         

            PatientSearchResponse ptLi = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PatientSearchResponse>(json2);

            foreach (PatientList3 patient in ptLi.PatientList)
            {
                searchResults[x].Add(patient.PatientNumber);
            }

        }
    }
}

public static string doPatientSearch(int UserID, int PracticeID, string SessionID, string PatientID = null,
        ,string first = null, string last = null, string dob = null,  string social = null)
{
    //search
}
```

My colleague suggested I change the method itself by removing all of the optional parameters and instead passing through a dictionary that contains all of the parameters and handling them inside the method.

I think that would work, but for curiosities sake I wanted to get some feedback and find out whether or not something like I'm attempting to do in the above code is possible.

If it is impossible but there is another way of achieving the desired outcome I'd love to see your suggestions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A dictionary suggests the parameters could literally be anything.  Instead I would use an Interface for truly public methods and Classes for any internal/protected/private methods.  `IPatientSearchCriteria` or `PatientSearchCriteria`.

Comment: How is the search physically performed? At some point is there a stored procedure call?

Comment: @JohnWu No stored procedure is performed. The parameters are used to build an API call.

Comment: What is the signature of the API call? Eventually whatever parameters you pass in will need to be mapped to the API, right?

Comment: @JohnWu If I'm understanding your question correctly, yes. The signature is being composed by the userID,  sessionID, and practiceID which are retrieved from the au object, whose structure and initialization I didn't include in the question because I didn't see it as germane. What I'm trying to do each iteration in the loop is pass different optional parameters using the dictionary search criteria and then compare the results after the fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pass an expression

Since the criteria are used post-hoc (i.e. by filtering a complete resultset), you can use LINQ to filter the results. For maximum flexibility, the caller can pass in an [Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) to be used as a callback on each item to determine if it should be included.

To get a filtered resultset:

```
public IEnumerable<Patient> FindPatients(Func<Patient,bool> criteria)
{
    return sourceData
        .Where (criteria);
}
```

To return a single result:

```
public Patient FindPatient(Func<Patient,bool> criteria)
{
    return sourceData
        .Single(criteria);
}
```

The `criteria` expression is just a function that accepts a patient and returns a Boolean. The caller can write this any way desired, or insert it as a lambda expression.

```
var results = patients.FindPatients( p => p.LastName == "Doe" );
```

Or

```
var results = patients.FindPatients
(   
    p =>
    p.LastName.Contains("Doe") && 
    p.PracticeID == 12 
);
```

Or

```
    var singleResult = patients.FindPatient( p => p.UserID == 1);
```

As you can see, the caller can provide literally any criteria desired, and has the benefit of type safety and early binding. This is far superior to using a Dictionary which has neither.

Full example code:

```
class Patient
{
    public int      UserID     { get; set; }
    public int      PracticeID { get; set; }
    public string   FirstName  { get; set; }
    public string   LastName   { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB        { get; set; }
    public string   Social     { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", UserID, FirstName, LastName);
    }
}

class PatientRepository
{
    static private readonly List<Patient> sourceData = new List<Patient>
    {
        new Patient
        {
            UserID = 1, PracticeID = 10, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", DOB = DateTime.Parse("1/2/1968"), Social="123456789"
        },
        new Patient
        {
            UserID = 2, PracticeID = 10, FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Doe", DOB = DateTime.Parse("1/2/1958"), Social="123456790"
        },
        new Patient
        {
            UserID = 3, PracticeID = 10, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Carson", DOB = DateTime.Parse("4/1/1938"), Social="123456791"
        }
    };

    public IEnumerable<Patient> FindPatients(Func<Patient,bool> criteria)
    {
        return sourceData
            .Where (criteria);
    }
    public Patient FindPatient(Func<Patient,bool> criteria)
    {
        return sourceData
            .Single(criteria);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //Get a reference to the data store
        var patients = new PatientRepository();

        Console.WriteLine("Multiple record search");
        var results = patients.FindPatients
        ( 
            p => p.LastName == "Doe" 
        );
        foreach (var p in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Single record search");
        var singleResult = patients.FindPatient
        (
            p => p.UserID == 1
        );
        Console.WriteLine(singleResult);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Multiple record search
1 John Doe
2 Jane Doe
Single record search
1 John Doe
```

[See the working code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lVU2OS)